# Socket closed when inserting to milvus pod on openshift

Tags: python, openshift, grpc

I have a pod running milvus in openshift, when I try to insert vectors into a collection I'm getting an error from grpc that reads socket closed.

**Environment details:**
I have played with the resources and tried giving it more and less resources with no effect.
I'm running milvus 1.0

This is the exact error i'm getting:

```
`Addr [ip:port] insert
Rpc error: <_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "Broken pipe"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1616758021.979269877","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:IP:port","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Broken pipe","grpc_status":14}"
```

**Additional context**

- The pod is running on openshift.
- I'm using a node port in order to use TCP.
- It seems that when I'm not adding a persistent volume the error doesn't accure, however after I'm a persistent volume the error accures even if I'm removing it.
- Some times for no apparent reason everything works without an error, but then 10 minutes after the first insert happens the error will come back.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the system is unavailable because of problems with external resources. For example, disk IO problems